# Java 8 convert the list and sublist into a single map

Tags: java, list, java-8

### How can we convert the list and sublist into a single map in java 8?

### Sample code

```
Map<String, String> pepAnswersMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Iterator<PepQuestionsDTO> iterator = pepQuestions.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    PepQuestionsDTO pepQuestion = iterator.next();
    pepAnswersMap.put(pepQuestion.getSign(), pepQuestion.getAnswer().getAnswer());
    for (Iterator<SubQuestionsDTO> iterator2 = pepQuestion.getSubQuestions().iterator(); iterator2.hasNext();) {
        SubQuestionsDTO subQuestion = iterator2.next();
        pepAnswersMap.put(subQuestion.getSign(), subQuestion.getAnswer().getAnswer());
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to explain what you want to do in your question. The code does not explain anything, and we are left wondering what you want your code to do which it doesn't do already.

Comment: i want to convet this looping section into java8 stream

Comment: Then write that in your question! While you're at it, edit the code so that it's a minimal working example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
pepQuestionsDTOS.stream()
            .flatMap(pepQuestion -> {
                pepAnswersMap.put(pepQuestion.getSing(), pepQuestion.getAnswer().getAnswer());
                return pepQuestionsDTO.getSubQuestions().stream();
            })
            .map(subQuestion -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(subQuestion.getSing(),
                                                     subQuestion.getAnswer().getAnswer()))
            .forEach(entry -> pepAnswersMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

however I think using of forEach loop is more readable

```
 pepQuestionsDTOS.forEach(pepQuestion->
    {
        pepAnswersMap.put(pepQuestion.question, pepQuestion.getAnswer());
        pepQuestion.getSubQuestions()
                .forEach(pepQuestion ->
                 pepAnswersMap.put(pepQuestion.getSing(), pepQuestion.getAnswer().getAnswer()));
    });
```